# Create file with text with dropbox api (rest or http)

Tags: rest, dropbox-api

I'm trying to figure out how to send a request to create a file with a simple string in it, but I cannot find the syntax to pass the string. Anyone able to help me out here?

The closes I've come is the following, but that would require a file to actually upload.

```
    https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload

{
    "path": "/compTest/test.txt",
    "mode": {
        ".tag": "overwrite"
    }, 
    "autorename": false, 
    "mute": false, 
    "strict_conflict": false 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Need-a-little-help-getting-started-want-to-write-a-simple-text/td-p/507454 ]

Comment: Yeah, still couldn't figure it out :)